# Change values of a cell using conditional looping

Tags: python, pandas

Question:

```
Rule    Percentage
AB      99.87%
CD      65.00%
EF      20%
GH      25%
IJ      0%
KL      17.70%
```

Check for the percentage value. If the percentage value is b/w 0%-20%, change the percentage cell value to 25%(Constant Value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and easy way:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Rule','Percentage'])
df['Rule'] = 'AB','CD','EF','GH','IJ','KL'
df['Percentage'] ='99.87%','65.00%','20%','25%','0%','17.70%'

# Replace values
df['Percentage'][df['Percentage'].str.replace('%','').astype(float)<25] = '25%'
```

Output:

```
  Rule Percentage
0   AB     99.87%
1   CD     65.00%
2   EF        25%
3   GH        25%
4   IJ        25%
5   KL        25%
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway using If condition ?

Comment: @NikhilG - I recommend asking a new/separate question for this. You should try to be as specific and detailed as possible in your question to avoid moderators closing it. It also helps if you can explain what you've tried so far.